# Chat environment that can interpret programming code

Tags: software-development, chat, collaboration

I am looking for a simple chat environment, were users can talk to each other, but at the same time write code in a programming language (maybe Python or Ruby or Bash, whatever).

Is there any way I could do that?
Or is there some plugin to existing clients I could use?

**Update** 
 - here are some, that appear as "SaaS", but I want to install it on my own Server.

- [CodeBunk](http://codebunk.com/)
- [CodeBox](https://www.codebox.io/)
- [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/)
- [Codenvy](https://codenvy.com/)
- [Codio](https://codio.com/)

I like CodeBunk the most, but it can't execute with user inputs.

**What I found so far :**

- [Collide](https://github.com/WeTheInternet/collide)
- [Codebox](https://github.com/FriendCode/codebox)
- [PythonSpeak](https://github.com/ziberna/python-speak)

Comment: What OS should it run on?

Comment: OS X would be great. I found "python speak" (https://github.com/ziberna/python-speak) , which is basically what I am looking for. And Maybe there is something better/ more stable.

Comment: you want REPL? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read–eval–print_loop   if so, the users must be trusted...even then...?